# No images or networks after running conjure-up openstack with Nova LXD

Tags: juju, openstack, conjure-up

I ran the conjure-up OpenStack with NovaLXD install and everything was green when it completed but for some reason when I log in the images networks and keypairs it said were created were not present.  At first I assumed it may have created them on a different domain but I checked all three that were created (admin_domain, service_domain, and default) and there are no images or networks in any of them.  Have killing the controller and re-running the install without any luck.

Comment: You've not actually asked a question. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to have access to the images and networks that conjure-up indicated it imported and created